# CSS responsive to bookmarks bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make my styles responsive to the opening of the bookmarks bar in the browser.

I have a media query watching the height of the screen.

When I drag the screen manually (reducing its height) the media query works as expected.

However, when I open the bookmarks bar, the viewport shrinks (past the point where it should trigger the media query, as per Chrome DevTools) but nothing happens.

1.) Why might this be?

2.) Is there a best practice for dealing with the bookmarks bar changing the size of the viewport?

### Update:

This is **not** a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396067/when-using-viewport-height-vh-in-css-does-it-include-the-browser-bookmark-bar) question.

That question asks if `100vh` takes into account the bookmarks bar. I am asking why my media query does not respond to the bookmark bar changing the pixel height of the viewport.

### Another update:

Link to example is here: https://n7m58rjj84.codesandbox.io/

Open in new tab, resize your window up and down and media queries work fine.

Try opening and closing bookmarks bar, and nothing happens.

[image: Edit n7m58rjj84]

Relevant code:

E.g. between small and medium breakpoints:

```
 `@media (min-height: 720px) and (max-height: 760px) { ... }`
```

Comment: I let your check [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396067/when-using-viewport-height-vh-in-css-does-it-include-the-browser-bookmark-bar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When using "Viewport Height/vh" in CSS does it include the "browser bookmark bar" in the total?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396067/when-using-viewport-height-vh-in-css-does-it-include-the-browser-bookmark-bar)

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Watching the size of the screen does not take into consideration the bookmark or tab height, you should instead use the viewport metric.
Could you be more precise about the behavior by adding some code

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, do you mean using vh instead of px? I updated question again.

Comment: Seen your code it might trigger by itself. Are you sure that opening your bookmark bar reduces the height enough to trigger the css media query. To check the real size, i suggest you use js to see the true viewport size for your debug

Comment: Yep, the bookmark bar is 40px high so it should definitely trigger it. I'm going by the Chrome DevTools measurements that show up in the top right of the viewport when resizing the page.

Comment: Maybe the 40px + height is not enough to trigger the media querry (switching from 720/760px to another size) ?
We don't have your setup

Answer (score 0):

Using this simple code and switching the bookmark display on and off:

```
<html>

  <head>

    <style>
    body {
      background: #0f0;
    }
    @media (min-height: 720px) and (max-height: 760px) {
      body {
        background: #f00;
      }
    }
    </style>

  </head>

</html>
```

It works fine

- tested in Chrome 72.0.3626.119
- tested in Firefow 65.0.2 (with personal menu bar)

**Make sure your tests includes the fact that you need to stay in this 40px range while modifying the viewport's height (760 - 720) otherwize the media query won't be tiggered**